# Specifying JSON data in In-App Purchase product's description

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Has anyone tried to specify JSON data in In-App Purchase product's description? I didn't notice product description showing anywhere. Will Apple approve such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, doesn't make real sense because it is permitted only 255 symbols in the description field.